# How to increase the volume in Movie Maker

Tags: audio, windows-live-movie-maker

When I export movie to High definition in **Windows Live Movie Maker 2011**, the sound volume differs about 40% from it's original, i.e. it is very low. While the **volume slider** in the audio options is **up to it's max**.

How can I prevent that Movie Maker decreases/normalizes the volume level, or increase it in the project file or program itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20111101030746/http://explore.live.com/windows-live-movie-maker-audio-editing-using)<sup>[archive link]</sup> is what you've already tried, your other option is to use [VirtualDub](http://virtualdub.sourceforge.net/). The only other suggestion is to use a program like [VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/) to amplify the audio with its own volume control as it plays.

1. Install VirtualDub

   1. Download the latest stable version of VirtualDub from [here](http://virtualdub.sourceforge.net/)
   2. Un-zip the folder
   3. Open VirualDub.exe
2. Add the video

   1. Click on `File --> Open video file...` and open the original video file
   2. Click on `Video --> Direct stream copy`
3. Modify the audio

   1. Click on `Audio --> Full processing mode`
   2. Click on `Audio --> Volume...`
   3. Check `Adjust volume of audio channels`
   4. Drag slider to desired amplification
   5. Click `OK`
4. Export the video and audio

   1. Click on `File --> Save as AVI...`
   2. Choose destination location and filename
   3. Click `Save`
   4. Let the video finish encoding

> If your video file is not supported by VirtualDub, you could try [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/downloads.php)
>
> 1. Install Handbrake
>
>    1. Download Handbrake from [here](http://handbrake.fr/downloads.php)
>    2. Open the installer
> 2. Transcode the video
>
>    1. Open Handbrake
>    2. Click `Source --> Video File` and locate your original video file
>    3. Click `Open`
>    4. Choose a destination with the `Browse` button
>    5. In the preset panel, select `High Profile`
>    6. Click the `Audio` tab and adjust the DRC to the desired level
>    7. Click `Start`

Comment: Handbrake is the one to use with windows live movie maker

Answer (score 0):

I have three versions of Movie Maker installed on my Windows 8 laptop and usually edit in MM 6.0. In that case, I've taken to using KMPlayer to capture (that's the menu it's under) the audio so I can then boost the volume in Audacity, export it from there as an MP3 (you can also export wavs and several other formats) and then finally import that version into Movie Maker. Tedious, but it works, and sometimes there's no other choice. Sometimes just capturing the audio with KM Player is enough, though, and then it can just be imported into movie maker.

Movie Maker 2.6 seems to play the existing audio louder than MM6.0 or Live does. Try to edit the same file with all three versions and 2.6 is the only one that starts with an option to make the audio even louder. The slider on the other two versions is already at the max, so if your audio is too low, there's no way to increase it there.

Answer (score 0):

I see it's a bit late but apparently I found how to fix that, Check this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awkcs6t5-d8
And from what it shows on 00:40, move the slider to the right to make it use ONLY the audio from the music!

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.